# Get thrown exception in finally block

Tags: c#, exception, finally

Is there a way, how to get currently thrown exception (if exists)?

I would like reduce amount of code and apply some reuse for task looks like:

```
Exception thrownException = null;
try {
    // some code with 3rd party classes, which can throw unexpected exceptions
}
catch( Exception exc ) {
    thrownException = exc;
    LogException( exc );
}
finally {
    if ( null == thrownException ) {
        // some code
    }
    else {
        // some code
    }
}
```

and replace it with this code:

```
using( ExceptionHelper.LogException() ) {
    // some code with 3rd party classes, which can throw unexpected exceptions
}
using( new ExceptionHelper { ExceptionAction = ()=> /*some cleaning code*/ } ) {
    // some code with 3rd party classes, which can throw unexpected exceptions
}

public class ExceptiohHelper : IDisposable {
    public static ExceptionHelper LogException() {
        return new ExceptionHelper();
    }

    public Action SuccessfulAction {get; set;}
    public Action ExceptionAction {get; set;}

    public void Dispose() {
        Action action;
        Exception thrownException = TheMethodIDontKnow();
        if ( null != thrownException ) {
            LogException( thrownException );
            action = this.ExceptionAction;
        }
        else {
            action = this.SuccessfulAction;
        }

        if ( null != action ) {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this scenario posible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you think about the following. Instead of looking at the problem as "How to get the last exception?", what if you change it to, "How do I run some piece of code with some more  control?"

For example:
Instead of an ExceptionHelper you could have an ActionRunner.

```
public class ActionRunner
{
    public Action AttemptAction { get; set; }
    public Action SuccessfulAction { get; set; }
    public Action ExceptionAction { get; set; }

    public void RunAction()
    {
        try
        {
            AttemptAction();
            SuccessfulAction();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
            ExceptionAction();
        }
    }

    private void LogException(Exception thrownException) { /* log here... */ }
}
```

It would at least give you some reuse of the SuccessfulAction and ExceptionAction assuming only the AttemptAction varies between calls.

```
var actionRunner = new ActionRunner
{
    AttemptAction = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Going to throw...");
        throw new Exception("Just throwing");
    },
    ExceptionAction = () => Console.WriteLine("ExceptionAction"),
    SuccessfulAction = () => Console.WriteLine("SuccessfulAction"),
};
actionRunner.RunAction();

actionRunner.AttemptAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Running some other code...");
actionRunner.RunAction();
```

Comment: Yes! The "Template method" design pattern is solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The idea is that you handle exceptions in the catch block...

That said, Exception is a reference type, so you can always declare an Exception variable outside the try scope...

```
Exception dontDoThis;
try
{
    foo.DoSomething();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    dontDoThis = e;
}
finally
{
    // use dontDoThis...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the way try-catch-finally. I use it now, as I said in the question - please read it one more time. But I want to reduce the writing code, and extend the reuse ability. This is not the answer in any way :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to catch unexpected exceptions you should be handling the [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx). You should only catch exceptions at lower levels that you intend handle (not just to log), otherwise you should let them bubble up and be caught at a higher level, or as I mentioned before in the UnhandledException method.

Comment: The UnhandlerException is a global event, and I lost every context informations - it is useless for concrete exception-handling in different code. However, this is better answr than @Mark Seemann. Maybe there can be some way, how to dynamicelly attach/dettach the UnhandledException. I'll try it.

Comment: The UnhandledException looks good, but if the exception is handled somewhere in caller code, the event is not raised (it makes sense - then is exception handled). But thanks, maybe I can found some "HandledException" event.

Comment: If you still want your Exception to get handled in the UnhandledException but you want to deal with it internally, just handle it and then rethrow it.

Comment: I want skip try-catch-finally blocks, because there is no efective way, how-to reuse it in large projects and manage refactoring is very time consuming.

The UnhandledException is raised only, if no catch-block is in above in stack trace. So if you have "void Main() { try { new Form1().ShowDialog(); } catch { ... }", the UnhandledException event is never fired.

Comment: @Tcks...not true. The UnhandledException event is raised if you do not *handle* the raised exception. Unless of course you are catching Exception (the base class) to which I would say is bad design.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very old question, but these days there are some possibilities.

[This github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/89724) contains an example of how this can be achieved:

```
async Task Main()
{
    using var activity1 = new Activity();
    try
    {
        using var activity2 = new Activity();
        await ThrowAsync();
    }
    catch
    {       
    }
}

public Task ThrowAsync() => Task.Run(() => throw new OperationCanceledException());

public sealed class Activity : IDisposable
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static GCHandle _currentExceptionHandle;
    
    static Activity()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s,e) =>
        {
            if (_currentExceptionHandle.IsAllocated)
            {
                _currentExceptionHandle.Free();
            }
            _currentExceptionHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(e.Exception, GCHandleType.Weak);
        };
    }
    
    private readonly IntPtr _exceptionAddress;

    public Activity()
    {
        _exceptionAddress = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var curentExceptionAddr = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();
        var isExceptionBubblingUp = _exceptionAddress != curentExceptionAddr && curentExceptionAddr != IntPtr.Zero;
        if (isExceptionBubblingUp && _currentExceptionHandle.Target is Exception currentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thrown exception {currentException}");
        }
        else if (_currentExceptionHandle.IsAllocated)
        {
            _currentExceptionHandle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```